# How to count numbers in a string separated by semicolon

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have multiple numbers in VBA like: 2;3;4;1.
And I need a VBA programm to make it possible to count those numbers.
So in one cell we have 1;2;3;4 and in the other cell all those numbers together.

I was thinking about something of a loop which take the first number and separate that from the rest of the numbers, then the rest of the numbers go into the loop again and it split one number again, and it keeps doing that until all numbers are gone. Only do I not know how to create something like that in VBA.
can anyone help me?

Comment: It would seem you are trying to invent either the [Text to Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) feature or the [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278528.aspx) function.

Comment: Do you like to count those numbers `1;2;3;4` is 4 numbers or do you like to sum them up which means sum of `1;2;3;4` is 10?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to split a string by a separator and count or sum the array.

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox CountInString("2;3;4;1") '= 4
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1")   '= 10
End Sub

Private Function CountInString(strIn As String) As Long
    Dim arrOut() As String

    arrOut = Split(strIn, ";")
    CountInString = UBound(arrOut) - LBound(arrOut) + 1
End Function

Private Function SumInString(strIn As String) As Double
    Dim arrOut() As String
    arrOut = Split(strIn, ";")

    SumInString = 0
    Dim strItem As Variant
    For Each strItem In arrOut
        SumInString = SumInString + Val(strItem)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

something you needed - assumed many things, and without errorhandling:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sum()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim summed As Integer
    Dim nums() As String

    i = 1
    While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        nums() = Split(Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value, ";")

        summed = 0
        For j = 0 To UBound(nums, 1)

            summed = summed + CInt(nums(j))

        Next j
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = summed
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the fastest way, but wanted to show another way of doing it.
Convert your `;` to `+` and evaluate the expression.

So using the function that @Peh wrote:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1")      '= 10
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "*") '= 24
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "-") '= -6
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "/") '= 0.66666667
End Sub

Private Function SumInString(strIn As String, Optional Operator As String = "+") As Double
    Dim sPart As String
    sPart = Replace(strIn, ";", Operator)
    SumInString = Evaluate(sPart)
End Function
```

You could even expand to:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "Count")     '= 4
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "Sum")       '= 10
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "Max")       '= 4
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "Min")       '= 1
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1")              '= 10
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "*")         '= 24
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "-")         '= -6
    MsgBox SumInString("2;3;4;1", "/")         '= 0.66666667
End Sub

Private Function SumInString(strIn As String, Optional Operator As String = "+") As Double
    Dim sPart As String
    Select Case Operator
        Case "Count", "Sum", "Max", "Min"
            sPart = Operator & "(" & Replace(strIn, ";", ",") & ")"
        Case Else
            sPart = Replace(strIn, ";", Operator)
    End Select
    SumInString = Evaluate(sPart)
End Function
```